# Disable the ability for contributor users to create Flow,PowerApp & Show/Hide columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, flow, powerapp

Seems in SharePoint online users with Contribute permission level are allowed to do a lot more than add/edit/delete list items. as seems they can create flows,create apps and show/hide columns inside the list forms as shown in the 3 screen shots:-
[image]

[image]

[image]

so can i Disable the ability for contributor users to create Flow,PowerApps & Show/Hide columns??

Comment: Are you sure they have "Contribute" permissions, and not "Edit"? They are not synonymous, "Edit" allows list and view structure to be changed, but "Contribute" does not. the default groups that come with a modern site do not initially have a "Contributors" group.

Comment: @willman yes they have contribute and not edit,

Answer (score 1):

For PowerApps and Power Automate (Flows) you can use the following:

> Set-SPOSite -Identity "URL of your site" -DisableFlows 1 -DisableAppViews 1